# Input text clear when I try to submit for a search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, input

Hello I have the following problem. I the site http://www.telefonkoll.se when I enter a number in the search and press the button then the text clears automatically and the result page return me all the results. If I don't use the jquery code it works correctly.

My jQuery code is this:

```
$("document").ready(function() { 
$("#mod_search_searchword").attr("value","Sök telefonnummer här");
});
$("#mod_search_searchword").live('focus', function (event) { 
$("#mod_search_searchword").focus(function() {
    $(this).val("");
  });
});
$("#mod_search_searchword").live('blur', function (event) {
$("#mod_search_searchword").blur(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == ""){ 
    $(this).val("Sök telefonnummer här"); }
  });
});
```

What I want to do with the above code is to clear the current text when the user click there. If it write something to still there, if not to return the initial text. It looks to work correctly but when I try to submit the data something wrong obviously happen. I don't know if it's the code or something I don't know.

Comment: Your code doesn't look too bad. I tried it on the web page and it worked there. Is the jQuery code installed at the URL you gave?

Comment: The code work, but for some reason I doens't submit the data, If you check it seems to clear it when you press submit. Without jquery it doesn't do it. The text appear there until show the results

Comment: You're aware that `"document"` in your `$("document").ready(/*...*/)` doesn't need to be quoted (the ` " `)? I don't know if that would make a difference, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @David Thomas thank you for the information. No it wasn't this the problem. I found out that some extra inline "onfocus","onblur","onclick" created the problem. I delete them with jquery and it's ok

Comment: No problem, I didn't really think it would be the solution (which is why I posted it as a comment), but just a snippet I thought might be useful in future. And I'm glad that you found a solution. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid [reinventing the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel). Use one of the [many](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) jQuery [watermark](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-watermark) plugins available.

Comment: I can't apply additional class or ID in any of the elements as most of these plugins require

Comment: @Sotiris, if you can call [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on those elements, I don't see what's preventing you from calling [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) on them as well :)